# SQL結果からツリー構造をもつJSONを返したい

Tags: python, sql, json

以下の例ようなSQLの結果からツリー構造をもつJSONを返すようなAPIを実現したいです。
なるべく高速でうまい方法があれば教えていただけないでしょうか。

■想定環境
sql: MySQL
言語：python3.9

### 例

#### SQL

```
select g.id as groupId, i.id as itemId, i.name as itemName, u.id as userId, u.name as userName 
from group g
left outer join user u on u.group_id=g.id
left outer join item i on i.group_id=i.id;
```

#### SQL結果

| groupId | itemId | itemName | userId | userName |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | itemA | null | null |
| 0 | 1 | itemB | null | null |
| 0 | null | null | aaa | userA |
| 0 | null | null | bbb | userB |
| 1 | 0 | itemA | null | null |
| 1 | 1 | itemB | null | null |
| 1 | null | null | aaa | userA |
| 1 | null | null | bbb | userB |

#### 期待するJSON

```
[
    {
        'groupId': 0,
        'items': [
            {
                'itemId': 0,
                'itemName': 'itemA'
            },
            {
                'itemId': 1,
                'itemName'; 'itemB'
            }
        ]
        'users': [
            {
                'userId': 'aaa',
                'userName': 'userA'
            },
            {
                'userId': 'bbb',
                'userName': 'userB'
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        'groupId': 1,
        'items': [
            {
                'itemId': 0,
                'itemName': 'itemA'
            },
            {
                'itemId': 1,
                'itemName'; 'itemB'
            }
        ]
        'users': [
            {
                'userId': 'aaa',
                'userName': 'userA'
            },
            {
                'userId': 'bbb',
                'userName': 'userB'
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

jsonのデータを柔軟に集計や操作できるToolzというパッケージの[groupby](https://toolz.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#toolz.itertoolz.groupby)で集約関数を利用できます。
ご質問のjsonフォーマットは独自形式のようですので、あとはループを使用して整形していく方法が正道のように思います。

参考資料: [python how to search a string, count values and group by in json](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60695373)

**サンプルコード**

```
import json
import MySQLdb  # ToDo: pip install mysql
from toolz import itertoolz # ToDo: pip install toolz

with MySQLdb.connect(
            user='root',
            host='localhost',
            db='mysql',
            charset="utf8") as con, \
     con.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor) as cur:
        sql = """ 
select 0 as groupId, 0    as itemId, 'itemA' as itemName, null  as userId, null  as userName union all
select 0 as groupId, 1    as itemId, 'itemB' as itemName, null  as userId, null  as userName union all
select 0 as groupId, null as itemId, null    as itemName, 'aaa' as userId, 'userA' as userName union all
select 0 as groupId, null as itemId, null    as itemName, 'bbb' as userId, 'userB' as userName union all
select 1 as groupId, 0    as itemId, 'itemA' as itemName, null  as userId, null  as userName union all
select 1 as groupId, 1    as itemId, 'itemB' as itemName, null  as userId, null  as userName union all
select 1 as groupId, null as itemId, null    as itemName, 'aaa' as userId, 'userA' as userName union all
select 1 as groupId, null as itemId, null    as itemName, 'bbb' as userId, 'userB' as userName
""" 
        cur.execute(sql)
        rows = cur.fetchall()
        json_rows = json.loads(json.dumps(rows))

        result = []
        # groupIdごとにグループ化しながらループ処理を行う
        for g_id, g_value in itertoolz.groupby('groupId', json_rows).items():
            group = {'groupId':g_id, 'items':[], 'users':[]}
            # itemsキー項目を整備する(同一のitemIdが複数存在する場合は先頭の項目のみ使用する)
            for id, v in itertoolz.groupby('itemId', g_value).items():
                if id is None:
                    continue
                group['items'].append({'itemId':id,'itemName':v[0]['itemName']})
            # usersキー項目を整備する(同一のuserIdが複数存在する場合は先頭の項目のみ使用する)
            for id, v in itertoolz.groupby('userId', g_value).items():
                if id is None:
                    continue
                group['users'].append({'userId':id,'userName':v[0]['userName']})
            result.append(group)

        print(json.dumps(result, indent=4))
```

**実行結果**

```
[
    {
        "groupId": 0,
        "items": [
            {
                "itemId": 0,
                "itemName": "itemA" 
            },
            {
                "itemId": 1,
                "itemName": "itemB" 
            }
        ],
        "users": [
            {
                "userId": "aaa",
                "userName": "userA" 
            },
            {
                "userId": "bbb",
                "userName": "userB" 
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "groupId": 1,
        "items": [
            {
                "itemId": 0,
                "itemName": "itemA" 
            },
            {
                "itemId": 1,
                "itemName": "itemB" 
            }
        ],
        "users": [
            {
                "userId": "aaa",
                "userName": "userA" 
            },
            {
                "userId": "bbb",
                "userName": "userB" 
            }
        ]
    }
]
```